# How to change IP of your server access from 0.0.0.0:8181 in Perfect 2.0?

Tags: swift, perfect

I'm new to server side programming, Since Perfect is out for Swift i am trying to get started with it.

I started PerfectTemplate and it's working on http://0.0.0.0:8181 but not accessible using my public ip i.e. say for example http://123.45.67.89:8181

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command+Click property "serverPort" it will take you to the implementation of HTTPServer.swift. There is another property "serverAddress" which is set to "0.0.0.0" by default.

you can change this by adding the following line

```
server.serverAddress ="123.45.67.89"
```

just above where you set

```
server.serverPort = 8181
```

However the new IP must be you're localhost IP found in system network preference. public IP address won't work in this case.

See the attached screen shot.

[image]